# How to recover ext4 partition deleted by WinXP?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, debian

Can somebody, please, help me with my problem!

I tried to delete the `/dev/sdb6` partition using Windows XP (Computer Management utility), but it actually deleted my Linux Debian Jessie! That is, it deleted: `/dev/sdb2`, `/dev/sdb5`, `/dev/sdb6`

I decided to post here, because the steps for recovery have to be the same for Ubuntu / Debian, if I understand it correctly.

Booting into the OS gives a black screen with the following output:

```
error: no such device: 9c5c34be-ca80-443b-8bdb-4d1ff2f8afaa.
error: no such partition.
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue..._
```

Currently, I was able to achieve the following.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb: 149.1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000080

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *           63  98301734  98301672  46.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2        98301735 312560639 214258905 102.2G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5        98301798 154625624  56323827  26.9G  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/sdb6       154625688 312560639 157934952  75.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

`/dev/sdb2` shows the wrong size. I presume `/dev/sdb2` has to be my swap file / partition with 2G size instead of 102.2G as the output shows.

`/dev/sdb5 26.9G` has to be my ext4 filesystem with Linux Debian Jessie where the data I need to recover badly is stored...

I've managed to successfully recover my `/dev/sdb6` partition by using `testdisk`, but no luck with `/dev/sdb5`.

Active@ partition recovery does not seem to see ext4 partitions.

**What can I do now to recover my `/dev/sdb5` partition OR at least recover files stored on that partition?**

Should I try `sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdb5`, etc. (just not to make things even worse)?

**UPD1**

deep scan with `testdisk` gives the following:

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 160 GB / 149 GiB - CHS 19457 255 63

The harddisk (160 GB / 149 GiB) seems too small! (< 240 GB / 224 GiB)
Check the harddisk size: HD jumpers settings, BIOS detection...

The following partition can't be recovered:
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>  HPFS - NTFS          19455 254 63 29286 253 62  157934952
```

Comment: If you download a Live Image ( Desktop ) and Boot in Live mode , you will have access to Gparted.
An alternative method would be reinstall ubuntu ,without formating , you wont lose your data Please tell us more about your problem

Comment: You could try scanning manually for the partition (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103919).  The first sector after sdb2 sounds like a good place to start.  mke2fs sounds like a bad idea, particularly if you don't know where the original partition started.

Comment: Don't overwrite your files with a new filesystem (after that, they're probably gone).  160Gb = 149GIB, divide the 160G by 1024 three times...  Your sector 2 is an extended partition, holding the logical partitions 5 and 6.

Comment: Just to say, I meant the end of sdb*1* would be a good place to start.  If sdb2 was recreated, it have been in the wrong place, and might have overwritten part of sdb5, but possibly just part of the first superblock, and there are other copies of it.  And yes, I guess `mke2fs -n` should be harmless, and if performed on a similar sized device, might tell you where other superblocks are.

Comment: @mwfearnley Thanks! @ubfan1 I've just recovered everything by running `testdisk` deep scan again. You are absolutely correct with your calculations. These were partitions 5 and 6!

Comment: @DmytroDzyubak That might be something you can add as an answer to answer your own question, and explain what you did to solve it in that answer.  (You are able to answer your own question, and in a day or two mark your own answer as accepted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know, deleting one partition could delete several partitions at once (till now)!

I ran `sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdb5` and the whole procedure as described in [HOWTO: Repair a broken Ext4 Superblock in Ubuntu](https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/) several times with reboot, but that did NOT help.

The following section of the guide **actualy helped me to solve my issue**: [TestDisk Step By Step - A partition is still missing: Deeper Search](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#A_partition_is_still_missing:_Deeper_Search)

- I ran deep scan / search again using `TestDisk` and this time (not
  sure what I've missed when I ran it the first time) it gave another
  output.
- Highlighting the partition and pressing the `p` button on my keyboard
  I've managed to find all the partitions that contained files.
- `Linux Swap` obviously doesn't contain any files, but has to be
  included too.
- Changing `D` to `L` (or `P`) includes the partition.

The end result looked like this:

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 160 GB / 149 GiB - CHS 19457 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 P HPFS - NTFS              0   1  1  6118 254 63   98301672
 D FAT16 LBA             6119   1  1  9624 254 63   56323827
 L Linux Swap            6119   3 29  6398 148 22    4491264
 L Linux                 6398 180 55  9624 229 13   51828736
 D HPFS - NTFS           6756 173 10 19457  21 20  204032000
 D Linux                 7982   9 28 11208  57 49   51828736
 D Linux                 7982 106 61 11208 155 19   51828736
 D Linux                 7986 127 14 11212 175 35   51828736
 D Linux                 7987   2 16 11213  50 37   51828736
 D Linux                 7997  85 25 11223 133 46   51828736
 L HPFS - NTFS           9625   1  1 19455 254 63  157934952
 D Linux                12835 104  6 13817 102 45   15775744
 D Linux                12839  91 53 13821  90 29   15775744
 D Linux                12843 242  8 13825 240 47   15775744
 D Linux                12844 149 42 13826 148 18   15775744
 D Linux                12850 245  4 13832 243 43   15775744
 D Linux                12851 250  8 13833 248 47   15775744
 D Linux                12858 220 35 13840 219 11   15775744
 D Linux                12861 203 15 13843 201 54   15775744
>D Linux                12862 175 50 13844 174 26   15775744
```

- Writing changes and rebooting got everything back again.