# My 1TB Internal Hard Disk lost 500GB partition ubuntu after deleted during windows installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

First, I've using Ubuntu. And then I try install Windows 10. When Windows required specific drive accidentally I format Ubuntu drive, and I also deleted it.

What makes me more fool is, I also assumed that If I delete the Boot Ubuntu I think it will be good. But what happened now is worse.

I really have no idea how to find and recovery Ubuntu partition now. I have try 'fdisk' command but it didn't work. I already try gparted but also didn't work.

So now, my fixed disk just 499GB left when I'm using Windows 10.

I have try a lot of software to recover partition but my disk still can't recovery to normally 1TB.

What I've try;

1. 4Digg software recovery
2. EaseUS
3. Diskpart
4. Medicat
5. I've tried access old ubuntu partition using lubuntu but it doesn't work.

I really needed help from all expert in here

Comment: Your desired goal is not clear. Do you want a 100% Ubuntu system? Or a 100% Windows system? Or dual-boot? Or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover ext4 partition deleted by WinXP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023436/how-to-recover-ext4-partition-deleted-by-winxp)