# Restore EXT4 Partition from NVME

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, data-loss, ddrescue

I have a server running on Ubuntu and OpenMediaVault 6 as NAS software on a VM. For data storage I use a seperate NVME. After restarting the server I could not connect from my other PC to my NVME storage any more. I logged in to OMV6 and wanted to mount my NVME disk (storeage) because it was not listed properly. Somehow however I did not click on mount but on Create and could choose the disk to create an EXT4 file system which I did. This was the moment I knew I messed up. My files from the NVME storage are not accessible any more.

I opened an Ubuntu VM and can only access the new created folder created by OMV6 but not the old files.

Could I please get some assistance on what might have happened and how I could try resolving the issue. Should I first try to restore the partition table or should I try to do a copy with ddrescue of the whole NVME.

Is there any chance to recover the files or is most likely everything lost?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Update 1.**

1. Made a copy of the NVME with dd
2. Running testdisk which finds the following as can be seen on the image below. When I go to the first result Linux filesys.data it only finds some folders/files which were added from OVM6 with the new EXT4. The second results says something like "no file found filesystem may be damaged" when I open it.

[image]

3. Could someone please explain what the above output means and what should be my next steps.

Comment: You may want to look at [How to recover ext4 partition deleted by WinXP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023436/how-to-recover-ext4-partition-deleted-by-winxp)

Comment: Yes Ubuntu is running on the host server. OpenMediaVault6 is running on a KVM Virtual Machine.

Comment: You may want to try TestDisk and or PhotoRec.

Comment: Ok thank you. Does it make sense to try first making a full copy with ddrescue?

Comment: If you have a second empty disk, making a full copy makes sense. That way, if something goes wrong you can start again from this point.

Comment: Could please someone help understand what the output in the attached image means. Thank you. I only find files with testdisk in one partition but not the ones I am looking for. What should be my next steps? Deepsearch or anything else?

Comment: I have never managed to use Testdisk (but I have read about successful usage of it). I have used PhotoRec successfully more than once (on USB pendrives). It can retrieve data directly from the memory cells, so independent of the file system and its addressing system. But the directory structure and file names are lost (except when the file name is also written as part of its content). So PhotoRec might be able to recover a fair part of your files, but it will cost a lot of work. - Please make frequent backups in the future and test that they really work (that you can restore from them).